# Save Email Addresses on Website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email, web

I have created a simple website and have a form that asks the user to input their email address to receive future updates from me.

What is the best way to save these emails. I am not anticipating having many so initially thought I could email them to myself every time someone submits theirs. I know how to do this using ASP.Net and Gmail. My questions then are:

1) Is there a way to accomplish this using just html and JavaScript and would this be better than having to use ASP.Net just for this one thing on my site (I haven't looked much into web hosting but I would have thought it would be cheaper to use just html and JavaScript)?

2) Is there a much better way to go about this that I have missed?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to accomplish this using just html and JavaScript

No

> Is there a much better way to go about this that I have missed?

Use real mailing list software or a third party mailing list service. This will save you from having to maintain the list manually (which is error prone) and (especially if you use a decent third party service) reduce the number of indicators that your emails are likely to trigger in spam filters.

Comment: I didn't even realise mailing list software existed. Thanks for the reply and the useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin mentioned you can't do this solely with HTML and JavaScript. You can either implement this youself (with ASP.net) or use a third party mailing service, which is the better option.

I recommend having a look at [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com) as they provide an excellent free service and you have the option of embedding a subscription widget on your website or you can always use their API to manage that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just HTML and JavaScript - the reason is that the data entered is on the client side (i.e. on the user's browser), and you can't ask the user's browser to send you an email.  You'd need to have the email submission send the data to your server or a third party server, which can then do what you want with the data.

Answer (score 0):

you should use one of server side Languages i recommend Asp.net you can use This

```
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailsmtp);
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailto, mailpass);
                string to = mailto;
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(mailto, "Form name");
                mail.To.Add(to);
                mail.Body = lbl_message.Text + "        " + lbl_name.Text + "        " + lbl_mail.Text;
                mail.Subject = "subj";
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Port = 587;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) it's very easy to add the sign up box to your site and it's free forever if you have less than 2000 subscribers and send less than 12000 mails per month. It also provides the facility to send great looking emails... If you implement your own system you'd need a way to send the mails, and your ISP may well prevent you mass mailing from your normal email account.